# what does this operator means in django `reduce(operator.and_, query_list)`

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am reading this questions

[Constructing Django filter queries dynamically with args and kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510057/constructing-django-filter-queries-dynamically-with-args-and-kwargs?rq=1)

I am not able to get what does this operator do

`filter(reduce(operator.or_, argument_list))`

or this

`filter(reduce(operator.and_, query_list))`

Comment: on a side note, `reduce` is now `functools.reduce` in Python 3 https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html#functools.reduce

Answer (score 18):

`filter` is a regular method of Django Model Manager, so there is nothing to explain.

`reduce` is a built-in function similar to the code below:

```
def reduce(func, items):
    result = items.pop()
    for item in items:
        result = func(result, item)

    return result
```

Where `func` is a user defined function.

`operator.or_` is a python standard library function that wraps the `or` operator. It is similar to this code:

```
def or_(a, b):
    return a | b
```

For example:

```
reduce(operator.or_, [False, False, True])
```

Will return `True`.

In your example context, the `or` and the `and` operators are overloaded and therefore it should return a new query combined of smaller parts all concatenated by `or` or `and` operator.

Comment: I main thing i want to know is `operator.and_` what does this do

Comment: Thank a lot! you explained in a few lines, what a couple of examples couldn't .The result = items.pop() explains why I got the error about types when I iterate over a object list and try to reduce a property of that object.

Answer (score 5):

[The Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) describe `reduce` as:

> Applying a function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of iterable, from left to right, so as to reduce the iterable to a single value

So it allows us to easily and quickly perform a single function (that takes two parameters, i.e. add a to b) numerous times over a set of data with one simple function call.

In the case of this Django problem, we want to construct a single `QuerySet` object by taking a list of individual query (`Q`) objects and cumulatively performing an `AND` or `OR` operation on them to get a single query

For example, for the queries `[Q(1), Q(2), Q(3)]` we want to `OR` `Q(1)` with `Q(2)` first, and then `OR` the result of that operation with `Q3` to give us our final query

We  are used to seeing operations in python (such as addition or subtraction) written like `A + B` (or in the case of or'ing: `A | B`) but python also provides functions to perform these (i.e. `or(a, b)`, and `and(a, b)` which would do the same thing). These are useful in situations such as these, as they can be applied as parameters to other methods. These functions such as 'add', 'subtract' etc. are in the `operator` module.

So using the `operators` module, we see that `reduce(operator.and_, query_list)` is taking each `Q` object in our list, and "and'ing" it with the ongoing results of the previous objects in the list.

Comment: is there any way of see the string representation of Q obejcts in query _list to see whta query it build. when i type `query_list` in shell_plus it gives me the Q object with some id. i want to know what query its building