# What is Q operator within reduce function is doing?

Tags: python, django

I am not sure what the following line of code is doing. I am sure its being used for the search but what is going within the reduce function.

Also i went through https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q
to find out similar examples for Q operator didn't find anything.

```
qgroup = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(**{fieldname + '__icontains': q_search}) for fieldname in fieldnames))
return queryset.filter(qgroup)
```

Question below did explained it a bit
[what does this operator means in django `reduce(operator.and_, query_list)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076894/what-does-this-operator-means-in-django-reduceoperator-and-query-list)

Comment: Relevant: [Pythonic List Iteration](//stackoverflow.com/a/18123727) and [django Building a queryset with Q objects](//stackoverflow.com/a/20222483)

Answer (score 2):

This just creates query with conditions separated by `OR` sql clause for every `fieldname` in `fieldnames` that contain `q_search`.

E.g.

```
fieldnames = ['name', 'text', 'content']
```

Would make

```
qgroup = Q(name_icontains=q_search) | Q(text_icontains=q_search) | Q(content_icontains=q_search)
.
```

So basically it filters your queryset if any of your fields in fieldnames contain `q_search`.

Comment: A bit of an example of how that query might look expanded would help.

Answer (score 0):

It implements OR between conditions, when simple filter can implement only AND between conditions