# How to construct dynamic Q() in Django

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I'm trying to filter dynamic value from a form in template to my query in Django project

the value can be dynamic, but it would look like this

```
first_query = ['a', 'b', 'c']
second_query = ['d', 'e', 'f']
```

what i want to achieve is to query something like this

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_1 = 'a' OR column_1 = 'b' OR column_1 = 'c' OR column_2 = 'd' OR column_2 = 'e' OR column_2 = 'f'`

Here's what i've done

```
        first_query = [ Q(column_1__contains=w) for w in first_query ]

        """
        If you print first_query
        [<Q: (AND: ('column_1__contains', 'a'))>, <Q: (AND: ('column_1__contains', 'b'))>, 
          <Q: (AND: ('column_1__contains', 'c'))>]
        """


        reduce_first_query = reduce(or_, query_first_query)
        """
        (OR: ('column_1', 'a'), ('column_1', 'b'),('column_1', 'c'))
        """
        

        second_query = [ Q(column_2__contains=w) for w in second_query ]
        reduce_second_query = reduce(or_, query_second_query)
```

When i try to filter Item from my database it gives me rows more than doubled than what i do directly from the database

`test_item = Item.objects.filter(reduce_first_query) # Gives 1900 ish rows, should be 900 ish`

What do i do wrong, is it because of the way i construct `Q()` ? or there other mistake ?

NOTES

- I'm using Postgresql 14

Comment: Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16077068/14457833)  this may help you to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

To produce the query that you specified, you need [in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#in) lookup, not contains:

```
first_query = ['a', 'b', 'c']
second_query = ['d', 'e', 'f']

qs = Item.objects.filter(Q(column1__in=first_query) | Q(columns2__in=second_query))
```

And btw, you can inspect the SQL query produced by ORM like this:

```
print(qs.query)
```